# Development -> Production pipeline

Tags: migrations, backups, staging

Is there any way that Development website can be passed to Production without overriding the nodes on Production. I tried the default backup and migrate modules but it overrides the existing nodes.

What tables I need to exclude ?
Would modifications on content types (changing and text to int) affect what is stored in the nodes table if that is outdated?

Comment: Databases shouldn’t go up the chain, only down. The only thing that should be getting deployed are configuration changes and then imported on production, which is a code only push, no database.

Comment: But what about theme config, block structure or module specific configuration? These are all stored in db.
Features for example does not move block layout

Comment: What about it? That’s all exportable configuration with core config management. You can obtain a full dump from the admin UI or with drush config-export

Comment: I didn't know drush has a config export. I am giving it a shot right now. But, admin UI? Where is the full dump option from there?

Comment: Enable the config management module in core and it will be a new option in the admin. You can then navigate to it and get a full archive file of the site configuration.